# How can I record video of the iPhone screen without jailbreaking the phone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to record video of the iPhone screen, and if so how?  I'm talking about video screen capturing, not using a camcorder or any app that requires jailbreaking my phone.

Comment: I think in iOS 5 there's a feature that lets you send video to a projector. That may just be for an iPad, but you'd be able to capture video from that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overlook the power of running things in the iOS simulator. Xcode is free for Lion users. This is a very limited solution since you aren't really on the iPhone and you can't run app store apps, since its running computer versions of the apps, not the ones you download from iTunes.

Being a paid developer allows some extra flexibility in capturing the screen while tethered, but this might be an alternate.

Until this becomes a feature, you'll be stuck with this and the other options you have ruled out - a real camera or jail breaking to modify the code and get a dump of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an iPhone 4S or iPad 2 you can use mirroring to an Apple TV, then connect the Apple TV to something that can capture its output. No jailbreaking required.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous commenter mentioned, video output is an option.

This appears to be available on the newer iOS devices (when loaded with iOS 4.x and later).

Check out **[this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4108)** from Apple about video out for iOS devices. You'll need a VGA adaptor for your device. You'd then be able to feed the video signal into another device that can record the signal.

So, you don't necessarily need to jailbreak to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a iPhone 4S or iPad 2, you could use the dock to digital video adapter into a video capture card.
The downside to this is the expense of purchasing extra hardware.